# Validação de dados no PHP

Tags: php, html, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto a qual estou utilizando uma estrutura um pouco semelhante ao do Laravel, essa estrutura me possibilita fazer um CRUD no sistema todo utilizando apenas uma classe e setando as tabelas de que desejo consultar. O código abaixo mostra como criei, fiz algumas validações básicas mas não sei se no caso é necessário validar os parâmetros de entrada para que a query não fique vulnerável contra sql injection ou se da forma que está já não está vulnerável.

```
<?php

namespace SON\Db;

abstract class Table{
    protected $db;
    protected $table;

    public function __construct(\PDO $db){

        $this->db = $db;
    }   
    public function insert(array $data){
        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($data)) . '`';
        $fields_data   = ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($data));
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO {$this->table} ({$fields}) VALUES ({$fields_data})");
        if($stmt->execute($data)){
            return true;
             // cadastro efetuado com sucesso !
        }
        return false;
         // error  - email inválido
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Então cara, você está basicamente adicionando os valores direto no sql, ou seja, o dados inseridos ali vão fazer parte da consulta. Como você não está se protegendo contra isso, é possível realizar sql injection. Sendo assim, você deve fazer algum processo de validação para evitar isso.

Comment: Tem alguma forma de validar os dados dentro do array para que não seja preciso separar os dados em várias variáveis ?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize um Framework não precisará se preocupar tanto com SQL Injection e Validações, se seguir corretamente as recomendações de uso do Framework.

Seguem alguns que podem ser úteis:

- [Cake PHP](https://cakephp.org/)
- [Code Igniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/)
- [Laravel](https://laravel.com/)
- [Symfony](https://symfony.com/)

O que não falta é Framework no mercado.

Não vale a pena reinventar a roda, inclusive novos Frameworks utilizam estruturas de Frameworks antigos, claro que deve ser verificada a licença antes de utilizar outro Framework como base.